# About <div ui-view></div> where to put in the code exactly

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, spring-boot

I am developping an application using bootstarap,Html and Angular js 1 for front .. it's an application spring boot indeed . i have a navar : the menu which i put in an index.html in static .. the other html file i put in static/views (divs) . Now when i started by adding "FicheFournisseur" which worked in the database and fine but now when i was structering my project i click on the "fiche fournisseur" in nav bar it don't take me the the div of FicheFournisseur.html .. After searshing i felt that something releated to angular js is not working :   i guess cuz whenever i change its position things change and am not understading am not familiar with angular js
 i put in the index 
i started with last li : Fournisseurs ui-sref="newFournisseur" do not take me to to page newFournisseur.html which came in other menus

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body ng-app="MyApp" >

        <div id="container">
            <!--BEGIN TOPBAR-->
            <div id="header-topbar-option-demo" class="page-header-topbar">
                <nav id="topbar" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0;" data-step="3" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <img src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/images/logo/logo.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="topbar-main"><a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="hidden-xs"><!--<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>--></a>
                        <a id="logo" href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><span class="logo-text" style="color: #fff; margin-left: 50px;">
                                SYSTÈME INFORMATISÉ DE SUIVI ET ÉVALUATION DES PROGRAMMES ET DES PROJETS PUBLICS </span></a>

                    </div>
                </nav>
                <!--BEGIN MODAL CONFIG PORTLET-->
                <div id="modal-config" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="close">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">modal</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>
                                    contenu du modal
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default"> valider</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">annuler</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--END MODAL CONFIG PORTLET-->
            </div>
            <!--END TOPBAR-->
            <div id="wrapper">
                <!--BEGIN SIDEBAR MENU-->
                <nav id="sidebar" class="nav navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation" data-step="2" 
                     data-position="right">
                    <!-- <ul class="nav__list">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#home" ><label><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Accueil </label></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul> -->
     
      <ul class="nav__list">
      <li>
        <input id="group-1" type="checkbox" hidden />
        <label for="group-1"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Suivi des marchés </label>
  
  
        <ul class="group-list">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
   
   
   
    <li>
    
     <input id="sub-group-6" type="checkbox" hidden />
     <label for="sub-group-6"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Consignation des marchés </label>
      <ul class="sub-group-list">
       <li>
       <input id="sub-group-2" type="checkbox" hidden />
       <label for="sub-group-2"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Fiche marché</label>
        <ul class="sub-group-list">
         <li class="active"><a href="test1.html">Fiche marché</li>
  
         <li><a class="" href="modification.html">Consignation avenant</a></li>                          
                      
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li class="active"><a href="#">yyy</a></li>
       <!-- insérer plus -->
             
      </ul>
    </li>   

    <li>
    
     <input id="sub-group-20" type="checkbox" hidden />
     <label for="sub-group-20"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Consignation des appels à la concurrence </label>
     <ul class="sub-group-list">

      <!--  <li class="active"><a href="#">ici</a></li>  -->
     
      <li>
    
       <input id="sub-group-3" type="checkbox" hidden />
       <label for="sub-group-3"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Fiche appel à la concurrence </label>
        <ul class="sub-group-list">
         <li>
          <input id="sub-group-4" type="checkbox" hidden />
          <label for="sub-group-4"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Fiche lot</label>
           <ul class="sub-group-list">
             <li class="active"><a href="fiche_activité.html">Fiche Activité</a></li>
             <li><a class="" href="">xxx</a></li>                          
             <li><a class="" href="">xxxx</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
        
         <!--<li class="active"><a href="#">Fiche lot</li>
                           
         <li><a class="" href="">xxx</a></li>                          
         <li><a class="" href="">xxxx</a></li> -->
             
        </ul>
       </li>
     
      <!-- insérer plus -->
             
     </ul>
    </li>
    
    
    <li>
     <input id="sub-group-1" type="checkbox" hidden />
     <label for="sub-group-1"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Fournisseurs</label>
      <ul class="sub-group-list">
       <li class="active"><a ui-sref="newFournisseur">Fiche Fournisseur</a></li>
       
         </ul>
    </li>
    
    

 
    
    
    
    
    
    
     <!--<li>
    
          <li><a href="#">xxxxx</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">xxxxx</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">xxxxx</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">xxxxx</a></li>
         
            <input id="sub-group-1" type="checkbox" hidden />
            <label for="sub-group-1"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Financement</label>
            <ul class="sub-group-list">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2nd level nav item</a></li>
              <li>
                <input id="sub-sub-group-1" type="checkbox" hidden />
                <label for="sub-sub-group-1"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span> Third level</label>
                <ul class="sub-sub-group-list">
                  <li><a href="#">3rd level nav item</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">3rd level nav item</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">3rd level nav item</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>-->
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
     
                    
                </nav>

                <!--END SIDEBAR MENU-->
                <!--BEGIN PAGE WRAPPER-->
                <div id="page-wrapper">
                    <!--BEGIN CONTENT-->
                    <div class="page-content">
                        <div id="tab-general">
                            <div class="row mbl">
                                <div ng-view></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--END CONTENT-->
                </div>
                <!--END PAGE WRAPPER-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--END PAGE CONTAINER-->
        <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       
   <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script> 
   <div ui-view></div> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: May be this can help you - http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:xyad7ztyMMOuKsK1TcKc?p=preview